# Separar conteúdo no menu CSS

Tags: javascript, java, css, java-ee, jsp

Estou querendo deixar   os links da paginas Controle Motoristas,Controle Passageiros,Controle Corridas, do menu um pouco mais separados mas espaçados, mas não estou conseguindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript">
     </script>

      <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">
       </script>
      <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css">
    <title>JSP Page</title>

    <script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="menu">

        <a href="index.jsp">Controle Motoristas</a></li>
    <a href="passageiros.jsp">Controle Passageiros</a></li>
   <a href="#">Controle Corridas</a></li>


</nav>
```

```
#menu {
background-color: #C0C0C0;
margin-top: 30px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
font-size: 13pt;
color:black;

}

footer{

background-color: #C0C0C0; 
margin-top: 350px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem a ferramenta do bootstrap que já tem algumas opções de navbar que ficariam melhor que essa que vc está fazendo meu amigo:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/
desça um pouco na página que você verá exemplos.

A sua  está recebendo as configurações do css, porém os seus links não, se vc quer fazer alterações no seus link coloque algum id neles, ou se quiser todos com as mesmas configurações utilize modifique a tag como um todo no css, caso você não se preocupe muito com isso, você pode usar os caracteres especias de HTML de espaço para fazer isso "&nbsp" é o caractere de espaço.